# Psychometric properties on new sample with old questionnaire

Tags: survey, psychometrics, cronbachs-alpha

When using a decades old inventory, questionnaire or factor from a questionnaire, is it important to retest the psychometric properties of this with the current sample, i.e. compute new Cronbach's alpha coefficients, CFA scores etc?

These questionnaires had good alpha scores back in the 60s & 70s but is decades old and is being used in a different country to where it originated.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best practice to re-validate a measure for your use cases. The case for doing that is stronger if (1) you had to translate it (and back-translate it) (2) the countries are very different (for some meaning of different) (3) it was developed a long time ago (4) it has not been used very often so experience with it is limited. Methods in psychometrics have also developed so you may find if you apply new up-to-date methods you would not get such promising results even on the original data-sets if you had them.